# How does gdb know if printed instructions are in arm or thumb mode?

Tags: printing, arm, gdb, instructions, thumb

Let's say you're in a gdb session and you're printing instructions of libc functions via x/[num_of_instructions]i [address]. How does gdb know whether they are to be interpreted as thumb or arm instructions?

Comment: it can only tell from hints left by the binary file format,  it is not possible to tell instructions from data or arm from thumb, etc...

Comment: unless you disassemble in execution order and even there a computed branch is essentially a dead end.

Comment: also understand that the gnu tools often dont get it right, there is some luck involved if it works...and this is not an arm/thumb thing but disassembly in general, look at x86 disassembly as a good example of this, one mode, still cant get it right all the time.

Comment: @old_timer: thanks